# Changing css top value makes element to disappear (website made in MUSE)

Tags: html, css, muse

I have a website made in MUSE. I tried to modify a specific value in the CSS code. In fact I wanted to make the top value in a percentage format.

So I changed top: ###px to ###%  but then the element in which this class was applied disappeared when testing it.

Original:

```
 #labelstrong
 {
    z-index: 17;
    width: 633px;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: justify;
    position: fixed;
    top: 1542px;
    left: 164px;
 }
```

New

```
 #labelstrong
 {
    z-index: 17;
    width: 633px;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: justify;
    position: fixed;
    top: 44%;
    left: 164px;
 }
```

It doesn't work. I even changed position attribute from fixed to relative and others with no results.

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle?

Comment: It's impossible.  It's a whole website with a lot of scripts and css. Do you have any idea wha could cause this? LEt's start from the code is it right? Do I have to change anything else if I put "top" in % ?

Comment: Theoretically not. It's really just it. I'll try to test another values. Also, you are sure there is nothing with a z-index higher than your `labelstrong` that could be hiding it right!?

Comment: If you could just set a fiddle with the html for `labelstrong` and the css you already posted, it will be easier to find out what is happening...

Comment: Well I'm starting to believe that it's somekind of a bug. Because in 100% it doesn't show anything when testing it.  But If I zoom out to 25% (everything will look tiny ) then guess what? It's there and then If I zoom back to 100% it will still be there until I refresh my page.

Comment: Ow, that's damn odd! Even it's being a bug, I would like to know why it's happening... How is `labelstrong` Html? Also, you don't have any JavaScript that interacts with this element?

Comment: Imagine a paragraph with id=labelstrong (this is how muse add classes). This paragraph has an <a> attribute as it's a target of a menu item. But I don't think that this has to do that much with this. :/

Comment: You haven't provided enough information to come up with a reasonable answer. There could be several causes for the invisibility (the place on the screen where it's displayed now is white; it's hidden behind another element, or you misunderstand what the `44%` is relative to, so it appears somewhere else than you expect; see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/neadumh4/1/) demonstrating these probems. Or, you say it's a bug in the browser, but you don't mention which browsers you have tested.